# how to format variables before db to avoid errors

Tags: python, mysql

I am recieving errors like this one:

`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't Stop.mp3' LIMIT 1' at line 1")`

Because I am trying to compare a URL that exists in my DB to one in a variable before I choose to insert it or not with the below code:

```
`#see if any links in the DB match the crawled link

check_exists_sql = "SELECT * FROM LINKS WHERE link = '%s' LIMIT 1" % item['link'].encode("utf-8") 

cursor.execute(check_exists_sql)`
```

Obviously the `'` character and perhaps other characters are causing problems.

How do I format these URLs to avoid this?

Comment: Do you know a guy called [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the `MySQLdb` module do the interpolation:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM LINKS WHERE link = %s LIMIT 1""",
    (item['link'].encode("utf-8"),)
)
```

The `execute()` function can be passed items to be substituted into the query (see [the documentation for `execute()`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute)). It will automatically escape things as necessary for the DB query.

If you prefer to use a dict instead of a tuple to specify the things to substitute in:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM LINKS WHERE link = %(link)s LIMIT 1""",
    {'link': item['link'].encode("utf-8")}
)
```

Comment: Cancel that... just errors when in my version where the sql string is separate from the `execute`

Comment: For the sake of completeness, one should note that the replacement characters (`%s`, `?`, `%(withdictionary)s`) vary across DB modules because [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) allows different parameter styles.